# JS передать значение формы в массив

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты, form

Как передать комментарий в массив **const comments = [];**
из формы нужно передать 2 значение, это id и сам комментарий (text)

```js
'use strict';

let nextId = 0;

const rootEl = document.getElementById('root');



const formEl = document.createElement('form');
formEl.dataset.id = 'comment-form';
rootEl.appendChild(formEl);

const descriptionEl = document.createElement('textarea');
descriptionEl.dataset.input = 'comment';
formEl.appendChild(descriptionEl);

const buttonEl = document.createElement('button');
buttonEl.dataset.action = 'add';
buttonEl.textContent = 'Добавить';
formEl.appendChild(buttonEl);

const listEl = document.createElement('ul');
listEl.dataset.id = 'comment-list'
rootEl.appendChild(listEl);

const errorEl = document.createElement('div');
formEl.insertBefore(errorEl, formEl.firstElementChild);

formEl.onsubmit = evt => {
    evt.preventDefault();

    errorEl.textContent = '';
    let error = null;

    const description = descriptionEl.value.trim();
    if (description === '') {
        error = 'Заполните поля Описание';
        console.log(error);
        descriptionEl.focus();
        return;
    }

    const comment = {
        description,
    };

    // Rows
    const rowEl = document.createElement('li');
    rowEl.textContent = `${comment.description}`;
    rowEl.dataset.commentid = nextId++;
    listEl.appendChild(rowEl);

    comments.unshift(comment);
    formEl.reset();
}

const comments = [];
console.log(comments);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попрбуйте так

```
// Rows
const id = nextId++;
const rowEl = document.createElement('li');
rowEl.textContent = `${comment.description}`;
rowEl.dataset.commentid = id;
listEl.appendChild(rowEl);

comments.unshift({
    description,
    id
});
formEl.reset();
```